# How to maximize application in over the Taskbar at Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to maximize my application in C# that it will be over the taskbar. I have change the property WindowState = Maximized. But the lower part of the application appears under the taskbar. I want the status bar to appear above with the taskbar also shown below it.

[image]

It's maximized but where is my statusbar :)

[image]

This is Normal State of Window; you can see status bar in this pic.

Comment: This might help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/c19872ab-8f3f-435f-a201-a36dea62ba98/

Comment: Size s = new Size(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height - 40);
Size = s; // this code is true solution ? TaskBar is 40 Px height i m lower it from Screen Res.

Comment: Your form doesn't seem to have a maximize button (or am I misreading the image?). Does it work correctly if all buttons are present (or absent) - and which effect are you trying to achieve - do you *want* your application to be fullscreen (no taskbar), or do you want the status bar to appear above with the taskbar also shown below it (I'm not quite clear from your description)

Comment: i want the status bar to appear above with the taskbar also shown below it thats what i want :)

Comment: Is this some kind of custom window theme?

Answer (score 3):

As I indicated in my comment, you've done something odd to your window, which is why you're getting this behaviour. I can reproduce this. I created a new WinForms project, put a button on the form that has this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Added a status bar, and **set the `MaximizeBox`** property of the form to **false**. Running the code, pressing my custom button, the form maximizes, but the status bar disappears behind the task bar.

If I then close the form, **re-enable** the `MaximizeBox` property, and re-run the project, then maximizing the form gets the behaviour you want (the status bar's bottom is aligned with the top of the task bar). So re-enable your `MaximizeBox` and you should be done.

(Once the Maximize box is available, maximizing works whether using that or the custom button)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you have no ControlBox, but text in the Form Text - this adds the title bar. Then, set your form `WindowState` to `Maximized`.

The last thing you do in the `Form_Load` event is to set the form `Text` property to an empty string. The Title bar is removed, the form is maximized, and the Task Bar is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you have TopMost property set to 'True'.  If you need this setting then you can get taskbar information from a Win32 API call.  There is some information about it here:

[Taskbar Height](http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=72452)

Otherwise you could just disable the TopMost setting.  You may want to check that your program runs in 64bit os (if you are not already using this).  I use VirtualBox with a 64 bit guest o/s for testing 64bit on my 32 bit host. (Requires a 64 bit processor though.)

I hope that this helps.

Comment: I think I have miss-understood the issue.  You have the start bar appearing over the top of you application instead of the bar being below you application?  Which version of Windows are you using and are all updates install?  What are your windows forms settings for this window?